# Can't debug gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, gulp

I have just installed the latest Gulp 4 (Local version 4.0.0-alpha.3). I have the most basic gulpfile.js which contains:

```
// Gulp 4
gulp.task('cleanTemp', function () {
log('Hello world!');
});
```

When I execute the code 
`node  --inspect-brk C:\Users\jdalecki\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp.cmd cleanTemp` to run it in debug mode, after I go to Chrome and press "inspect" in the page "chrome://inspect/#devices", I am always getting:

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/391dc461-3229-49a0-a400-c5374386b89f
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
C:\Users\jdalecki\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp.cmd:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
                                                              ^
    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
    Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

What am I doing wrong?

Kind Regards,
Janusz